# Why when pickling this array is the last value lost?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, pickle

I am trying to write ingredients for a recipe into an array to be pickled and re-opened later for further use. The program needs to be able to take any number of ingredients so loops three inputs by the amount of ingredients.

```
recipedetails=[] #starts array

for i in range (ing_number): #Loops 3 intented code by in_number amount of times
    ing_name = input ("Enter ingredient name: ") #Ingredient name variable
    ing_amount = int (input ("Enter quantity of ingredient ")) #Quantity variable
    ing_unit =  input ("Enter unit of ingredient: ") #Unit variable

    recipedetails.append ((ing_name, ing_amount, ing_unit)) #closes array

    recipe = open(rec_name+".dat", "wb") #Creates .dat file with recipe name as file  name.
    pickle.dump(recipedetails, recipe) #Adds this info to .dat file
```

However, when I input, for example 4, ingredients the array only saves 3 to the .dat file. I don't understand why this is happening as it doesn't overwrite the last ingredient, it seems it just ignores it. How do I get all looped variables added to the array and the .dat file?

```
 print ("Create Recipe") #Shows user has opted to create recipe

 rec_name = input ("Enter recipe name: ") #Prompts user for recipe name.
 ing_number = int (input ("Enter number of ingredients: ")) #Prompts user for number of ingredients
 people = str (input ("Enter number of people: ")) #Prompts user for number of people

 f = open(rec_name+"people.txt", 'w')
 f.write(people)
 f.close()

 recipedetails=[] #starts array

 for i in range (ing_number): #Loops 3 intented code by in_number amount of times
     ing_name = input ("Enter ingredient name: ") #Ingredient name variable
     ing_amount = int (input ("Enter quantity of ingredient ")) #Quantity variable
     ing_unit =  input ("Enter unit of ingredient: ") #Unit variable

recipedetails.append ((ing_name, ing_amount, ing_unit)) #closes array

recipe = open(rec_name+".dat", "wb") #Creates .dat file with recipe name as file  name.
pickle.dump(recipedetails, recipe) #Adds this info to .dat file
print (recipedetails)#Prints ingredients that user has added.
```

Added full code

Comment: Is this your actual indentation? I think you need to dedent the last two lines out of the `for` loop.

Comment: Please post an example that *runs* and demonstrates the problem. The code posted will not run by itself (missing `import`, missing initialization of `ing_number` and `rec_name`, etc).

Comment: Yeah when I do dedent it gives me the "unindent does not match any outer indentation level" no matter where I put it  doesn't make sense

Comment: Well the top example is clearly wrong as you're pickling inside the for-loop. In the second example your append is happening outside the for-loop, so that's also clearly wrong. You really need to clean up your code so that if you do a `print(recipedetails)` before the pickle, you get what you expect to. Then we can work on debugging the pickle.

Comment: I am a massive idiot the pickling in the loop was the issue

Comment: I voted to close because this seems like a typo error and not an error in code.